# Spring Transaction management

Tags: java, spring, transactions

In java Spring, I am facing an issue regarding transaction rollback.

Example:

I have 3 DAOs in my code (A, B, C). All of them extend `JDBCTemplate`:

```
@Transaction(propagation=new_required)
public void serviceClassProc() throws Exception {
   A.db1();
   B.db2();
   C.db3();
}
```

Now with the above code if I throw an exception in `B.db2()`, nothing gets rolled back.

Now if I modify `B.db2` as following:

```
@Transaction(propagation=nested,rollbackon=Exception.class)
public void db2() throws Exception{
...
throw new Exception();

}
```

And then call `serviceClassProc()`, only the transaction in `B.db2`, gets rolled back.

I want an implementation where all transactions inside `serviceClassProc()` get rolled back.

Here are the 2 configurations I am using:

```
<bean id="bonddao" class="com.marki.bonds.staticdata.dao.MuniStaticDataDaoImpl"> <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" /> </bean> <bean id="dcldao" class="com.bonds.staticdata.dao.DclSettingsDaoImpl"> <constructor-arg ref="c3p0DataSource" /> </bean> <bean id="batchlogdao" class="com.bonds.staticdata.dao.MuniFeedHandlerBatchLogDaoImpl"> <constructor-arg ref="c3p0DataSource" /> </bean>

<bean id="bondsApplication" class="com.markit.bonds.staticdata.service.MuniRefDataSyncApp"> <property name="refdataService" ref="refDataSynchService" /> <property name="mailService" ref="mailSender"></property> <property name="batchLogger" ref="batchlogdao"></property> </bean> <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"> <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" /> </bean> <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Where I am going wrong?  Is it wrong to have 3 DAOs all extending JDBC template?  Should all of them share same JDBCTemplate?

Comment: I don't know if this is correct, but it would be logical to put rollbackon=Exception.class in the @Transaction annotation that is on the serviceClassProc method. Have you tried that?

Comment: Please post the xml configuration for the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, JdbcTemplate, TransactionManager

Comment: What kinds of exceptions are being thrown?  Note that by default, Spring will only mark txs for rollback if the exception extends `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 3):

You should add `rollbackon=Exception.class` to the annotation of your service method and remove the transaction annotation entirely from the DAO methods. It is a bad idea to have transaction control at DAO level.

Comment: I tried rollbackon=Exception.class but it didn't work. Somewhere i feel that all three dao's extend jdbctemplate means all three transactions have their own connection. I am not sure if that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also the : `**org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;**`

here is an example that you can handle it:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public void messageHandler() {
            try {
                //TODO your own code

            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
            } finally { 

            } 

}
```